# Simple query how to join

Tags: mysql

1St Table (student)

```
|name |  matricNo |  Subject  |
|John |  A01      |  History  |
|John |  A01      |  Math     |
|John |  A01      |  Language |
```

2Nd Table (remark)

```
|name |  matricNo |  Subject  | Grade |
|John |  A01      |  History  |   A   |
|John |  A01      |  Math     |   B   |
```

**I have make the query,**
**So the output like this**

**query = select a.*,b.grade from student a left join remark b on(a.matricNo=b.matricNo)**

```
|name |  matricNo |  Subject  | Grade  |
|John |  A01      |  History  |  A     |
|John |  A01      |  Math     |  B     |
```

**but i want output like this:-**

```
|name |  matricNo |  Subject  |  Grade  |
|John |  A01      |  History  |   A     |
|John |  A01      |  Math     |   B     |
|John |  A01      |  Language |  NULL   |
```

**i already try left join and right join also give me the same output.**

Comment: At first you must normalize your DB. You first query must return desired result and more. select a.*,b.grade from student a left join remark b on a.name =b.name and a.matricNo=b.matricNo and a.Subject  =b.Subject

Comment: To get what you need, you need separate table with Subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do join to all the columns in table student like below

```
select t1.*,t2.grade from student t1 
left join remark t2 on t1.name =t2.name and t1.matricno=t2.matricno and t1.subject =t2.subject
```

This is working [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9850d/3)